# display data in grid-view

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I try to display data in gridview through linq this is what i try

```
public void vehcile(string id)
        {
            Entities1 wr = new Entities1();
            List<spchile_Result> sv = wr.spchile(id).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Number",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));


            foreach(var c in sv)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(c.Number,c.RegNo)
            }
            GridView1.DataSource=;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            return dt;

        }
```

**UPDATE**

ok now i am going to minimize no. of code lines and directly bind instead of add columns when i do this show error

```
 public DataTable vehcile(string id)
        {
            Entities1 wr = new Entities1();
            GridView1.DataSource=wr.spvechile(id);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            return ;
        }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.vehcile(id);
            }

        }
```

this show error

Error   10  An object of a type convertible to 'System.Data.DataTable' is required
Error   9   The name 'id' does not exist in the current context 
now how i return data and how i set data source?

any solution's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      public DataTable vehcile(string id)
    {
        Entities1 wr = new Entities1();
        List<spchile_Result> sv = wr.spchile(id).ToList();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Number",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));


        foreach(var c in sv)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(c.Number,c.RegNo)
        }
        GridView1.DataSource=dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        return dt;

    }
```

Comment: you want to return datatable then you need to create it and fill the data in it. dt is the object of datatable. u need to return dt.

Comment: but when i call id on page load this show error also

Comment: what is the value of id.how do you get the value of id?

Comment: i pass id parameter in sp .. and then call this in function

Comment: Yes, I can see that, But where do you get value of id? declare "id" as public class member.Like (public int id=0; )

Answer (score 0):

Set value of `DataSource` which is `dt` in your case.

```
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Also `return type` of your method is `void` and you are returning `DataTable` which will result in error.

If you are planning to return `DataTable` change `return type` to `DataTable`

```
public DataTable vehcile(string id)
{
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource=sv;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

why you need to return data your return type is void.

you can return like

```
public List<spchile_Result> yourmethod(int id)
{
    ...
    return sv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set data table as data source of grid view and return type of method should be `DataTable` instead of `void`

```
       GridView1.DataSource=dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: your return type is datatable but not returning datatable.(return dt is missing)

Comment: like this  return DataTable;?

Comment: public DataTable vehcile(string id)
        {
            Entities1 wr = new Entities1();
            List<spchile_Result> sv = wr.spchile(id).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Number",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));


            foreach(var c in sv)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(c.Number,c.RegNo)
            }
            GridView1.DataSource=dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            return dt;

        }